# Point admin button url to different custom module

Tags: magento2.4, xml

```
<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
        </item>
    </item>
```

What can I replace `*/*/addrow` with?

Comment: hey @Shaun. If the answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**, it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `url` path of the button has the following format: `<front-name>/<controller-name>/<action-name>`

For example, you would like to point to CMS Page Listing:

Replace `*/*/addrow` to `cms/page/index`